# How to synchronize two independent NSManagedObjectContext in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two NSManagedObjectContext which are independent: there is no relationship between the two. How to synchronize the two in Core Data?

Comment: What do you mean they are independent? Do they not have the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`? Independent to me means each if for its own database in which case you need to fetch all objects from one DB with one context and then fetch or generate all objects in the second DB with the second context. If they are in the same database then you just need to save data with one context and refetch objects with another. In any case I see no logical meaning to "synchronize the two".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that if you are having two context like on is in background thread and other is on main thread for example then you can use

mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

to synchronize the data of two managed object context

```
// MARK: -
// MARK: Notification Handling
func managedObjectContextDidSave(notification: NSNotification) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.mainManagedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

You can refer whole tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-concurrency--cms-25118)