# Saving data in background thread doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save my data in CoreData in background thread, but it crash or it doesnt work, any idea where am I doing the mistake?

When I try with main thread it works correctly, I tried to google to find some information in background thread, I couldn't find some useful article about it.

any help appreciate.

Thanks

This is the objective -c code, what I tried

```
-(void)insertNameAndSurnameInDataBase:(NSString *)name surname:(NSString *)surname numbers:(NSArray *)numbers labels:(NSArray *)labels{




    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    [backgroundMOC performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
    NameAndSurname *nameAndSurname = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NameAndSurname" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundMOC];
    NSString *nSurname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",name,surname];
    nameAndSurname.nameSurname = nSurname;


    if ([backgroundMOC save:&error]) {
    }
    else{

    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NameAndSurname"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:backgroundMOC];


    // predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameSurname =[c] %@", nSurname];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray  *fetchedObjects = [backgroundMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
         if([fetchedObjects count] > 0){
             [numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                  id obj2 = [labels objectAtIndex:idx];
                 obj = [obj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];



                 ContactNumber *phoneNumber = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ContactNumber" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundMOC];
                 phoneNumber.number = obj;
                 phoneNumber.label = obj2;
                 phoneNumber.nameAndSurname = fetchedObjects[0];
                 NSError *error;
                 if ([backgroundMOC save:&error]) {
                 }
                 else{

                 }

            }];
             }

    }];
         }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Hi @m1sh0  the error is:  [EXCEPTION] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'NameAndSurname''

Comment: The problem is that you have two contexts and you need to merge the data

Comment: Can you plz provide an example?  you mean NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy?

Comment: look this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47904041/1856499

Comment: Thanks didnt help.